# Select Date.today from date_select in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with a date_select which shows 3 selectboxes for day, month and year. I have a rspec integration test where I want to select today's date with capybara. So I have to split Date.today into a day, month and year. What's a good way to do this? I could do some string splits, but maybe there is a more sophisticated way to do?

Here you see the capybara code to select the date hard coded:

```
select("13", :from => "visit_visit_date_3i")
select("July", :from => "visit_visit_date_2i")
select("2012", :from => "visit_visit_date_1i")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods for extracting date parts from a Date object. The date class also has some constant arrays that make it easy to convert things like months and days of the week to their English versions.

Thus:

```
Date.today.day 
=> 13
Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month] 
=> "July"
Date.today.year 
=> 2012
```

All this is in the docs for Date, which are located [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [timecop](http://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop.git) to freeze the current date. This comes in handy later when testing whether other methods that deal with 'today' or 'one week from today'

```
before { Timecop.freeze(Date.parse("Jul 13 2012") }
after { Timecop.return }
```

Now you can `select("13", :from => "visit_visit_date_3i")` and it will work for any date on which the test is run.